# cURL (or similar) to submit data to a flash site

Tags: curl, actionscript

Ive got a little project which im using a couple of api's to gather and submit data from websites, in the absence of an api im using cURL to do the tasks.

But two sites im using are flash, one of them has a mobile site which is html / css / jquery so i can send the bot to use the mobile site, but the other site is pure flash, no html fall back, is there a way i can submit forms, and grab data from this site ?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Send data from flash directly to some server? Pass data to your flash from the HTML wrapper?

Comment: @YaronU. im trying to submit a form and then return the form confirmation message